Как не допустить множественное нажатие на кнопки в Aiogram?
У меня есть телеграмм бот написанный на aiogram и там есть как Inline так и Keyboard кнопки.Как можно не допустить двойного тройного нажатия на них в течении минуты?

Как вариант, сделать пометку в базе данных, когда последний раз нажимал пользователь и сделать ограничение, что если с последнего нажатия не прошло минуты, то не производить действий.

Ещё вариант с помощью datetime и словаря, но при условии, что оперативной памяти хватит на всех пользователей.

@mrBars1k да так конечно можно, думал может быть просто какое то дополнение есть к aiogram чтобы так проверять, а не через бд(.Да и мне прям именно минуты вымерять и не нужно там просто чтобы от дабл клика уберечь программу, а то некоторые нажимают по 2-3 раза и код выполняется несколько раз для них, да и ошибки выходят из-за этого

Я Aiogram не так давно использую, но кажется в старой версии был механизм для предотвращения, тротлинг назывался кажется. Но в логах V3 написано, что эту фичу выпилили и нужно самостоятельно делать механизм.
В своём боте я делал с помощью БД механизм блокировки на 3 секунды, потому что если заспамить, то данные не успевали обновиться, а новый запрос уже происходит. И возникали ошибки и обходы лимита выдачи данных работникам.

по запросу "Throttling Middleware aiogram" найдете ответ

Попробуй так
   async def anti_flood(*args, **kwargs):
    m = args[0]
    await m.answer("Не флуди")

   @dp.callback_query_handler()
   @dp.throttled(anti_flood, rate=1) #1 нажатие в секунду
   async def code(....):
       #код

Если использовать Throttled то в случае если пользователь нажмет на кнопку больше одного раза в секунду то сработает функция anti_flood

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
